# iOS uiwebview is firing finishLoad event before load whole html file

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am loading a static html file on a uiwebview and when webViewDidFinishLoad, I am inserting following javascript to get data contained on a div.

```
NSString *body = [self.webView1 stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                              @"document.getElementById('social').innerHTML"];

NSLog(@"received data: %@", body);
```

All seems that is working properly but sometimes div is empty!! Assuming that div is always filled because div is static, I am thinking that webViewDidFinishLoad event is fired before whole page is loaded and javascript then looks for that div that is not ready yet. Possible? If not, any suggestion? How to solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I have noticed sometimes webViewDidFinishLoad gets fired before you think it should. I can't remember the details off the top of my head, but it may be when redirects are involved.

When it gets called you could check if the page is still loading:

```
if (webView.loading)
    return;
```

Or you could use a javascript function which registers an event listener for when the dom has loaded, and when it has use the location.href technique to trigger your webViewShouldStartLoad with a custom scheme to notify your code the dom has finished loading.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Webview.loading return false also when empty value appears! testing second option...